# Solving a qusilinear PDE - am I missing a clever trick?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

I'm more or less familiar with the characteristic method for solving a quasilinear PDE. I've tried to apply it to the following problem, but I having difficulties:
$$
u(x+u)u_x - y(y+u)u_y = 0 \\
u(1, t) = \sqrt{t}
$$

When writing down the characteristic equations:

$$
x_s = u(x+u) \\
y_s = -y(y+u) \\
u_s = 0
$$
(t stands for initial curve parameterization, s stands for characteristic parameterization)
I do manage to find that:

$$
u(s) = C_1 (t)
$$
And substituting the initial condition provides:$u = \sqrt{t}$. I find that suspicious, since I think this implies that $u=\sqrt{y}$ which does not satisfy the equation. Since I had no better idea, I was trying to solve the other two equations (note that u is constant with respect to s):
$$
ln(x+u) = us + C_2(t) \\ 
\frac{1}{u}(ln(y) - ln(y+u)) = -s + C_3(t)
$$

Which I can not seem to infer u or t in terms of x, y .
Anyway, I think I've either:

1. blew it along the way
2. I'm missing some clever trick that should make solving a lot easier
3. Am not applying the method of characteristics well

Please share your insights with me.
Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost had it!

You're right that $u=\sqrt{t}$, but what that means is that $u$ is constant along the characteristic curve corresponding to the parameter value $t$, so you're wrong in thinking that it implies that $u(x,y)=\sqrt{y}$.

Anyway, finishing the calculation that you started, we find that the characteristic curve going through the point $(x,y,u)=(1,t,\sqrt{t})$ when $s=0$ is
$$
\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ u \end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
(1+\sqrt{t}) \, e^{s \sqrt{t}} - \sqrt{t}
\\[1ex]
\dfrac{t}{(1+\sqrt{t}) \, e^{s \sqrt{t}} - \sqrt{t}}
\\[1ex]
\sqrt{t} \end{pmatrix}
,
$$
where somewhat miraculously the relation $y=t/x$ happens to hold. In other words, the characteristic curve corresponding to the parameter value $t>0$ is nothing but the curve $xy=t$, or more precisely it's the branch of that curve which lies in the first quadrant $x>0$, $y > 0$. And since $u$ is constant on each such curve, we find that
$$
u(x,y) = \sqrt{\strut xy}
,\qquad
x>0
,\quad
y>0
.
$$
Remark 1: The given initial data only specifies $u=\sqrt{t}$ at the points $(x,y)=(1,t)$ where $t \ge 0$, because of the square root, and the characteristic for $t=0$ is simply the $x$-axis, where $u=\sqrt{xy}$ isn't differentiable, so we need to exclude $t=0$ and keep only $t>0$.

Remark 2: You can (and should) check directly that $u=\sqrt{xy}$ indeed satisfies the PDE and the initial condition.

Comment: Hey Hans - Thanks a million. I'm trying to highlight the stuff I've missed and maybe maximize learning from your answer.  Would you be kind enough to explain what does it mean for u to be constant along the curve corresponding to the parameter t? I feel I almost understand it but not quite

Comment: @NG_: For each $t>0$, there's the point $(x,y,u)=(1,t,\sqrt{t})$, and you compute the characteristic curve in $(x,y,u)$-space starting at that point. In this specific example, where $u_s=0$, that curve will stay on the same height $u=\sqrt{t}$ all the time, and you need only compute the $x$ and $y$ components. That curve in the $(x,y)$-plane, which is the projection of the characteristic curve in $(x,y,u)$-space, is then a level curve of the solution $u(x,y)=\sqrt{xy}$. Does that make it any clearer? It's a bit hard to explain without drawing pictures...

Comment: It actually does make it clearer. Your help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

$$u(x+u)u_x - y(y+u)u_y = 0$$
Charpit-Lagrange characteristic ODEs :
$$\frac{dx}{u(x+u)}=\frac{dy}{-y(y+u)}=\frac{du}{0}=ds$$
A first characteristic equation comes from $du=0$ :
$$u=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx}{c_1(x+c_1)}=\frac{dy}{-y(y+c_1)}$

$\frac{dx}{dy}+\frac{c_1}{y(y+c_1)}x=-\frac{(c_1)^2}{y(y+c_1)}\quad$ is a first order linear ODE. Solving it for $x(y)$ leads to :

$x=\frac{(c_1)^2+c_2(c_1+y)}{y}$

$$\frac{xy-(c_1)^2}{c_1+y}=c_2$$

The general solution of the form of implicit equation $c_2=F(c_1)$ , with $c_1=u$ is :
$$\boxed{\frac{xy-u^2}{u+y}=F(u)}$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function (to be determined according to the specified condition).

Condition : $u(1,t)=\sqrt{t}$

$\frac{t-(\sqrt{t})^2}{\sqrt{t}+t}=F(\sqrt{t})=0$

The function $F=0$ is known now. We put it into the above general solution.
$$\frac{xy}{u+y}-\frac{u^2}{u+y}=0\quad\implies\quad u^2=xy$$
$$\boxed{u(x,y)=\sqrt{xy}}$$
The root $_:-\sqrt{xy}\:$ is excluded because the condition implies $u\geq 0$.